# Commuting permutations are multiples of each other

Tags: group-theory

Assumptions: Let $\alpha$ be a permutation represented as disjoint cycles $\alpha=c_1\circ \dots \circ c_r$ with respective length $\lambda_1 ,...,\lambda_r$ such that $\lambda_i\neq \lambda_j$ if $i\neq j$.

Statement: If now $\beta\alpha=\alpha\beta$ then $\beta=c_1^{z_1}\circ...\circ c_r^{z_r}$ for integers $z_1,\dots,z_r$.

My attempt: The commututing relation $\beta\alpha=\alpha\beta$ says that the permutations are conjugate and hence share the same signature/cycle type. My hope was, that one can then compare cycles of same lenght but I go stuck there.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Does the commuting relation really say that the permutations are conjugate? Can you say what you’re using there?

Comment: Oh I see, $\alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}=\beta$ only says that $\beta$ is conjugate to itself via $\alpha$. This seems to be of no help. However, I know that if $\alpha=(a_{11}...a_{1l_1})...(a_{s1}...a_{1l_s})$ then $(\beta a_{11}...\beta a_{1l_1})...(\beta a_{s1}...\beta a_{1l_s})=\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}$. Can I continue from here?

Comment: I don’t think it’s at all true that commuting permutations are powers of each other. I hope you don’t need this for other aims.

Comment: I thought the assumption $\lambda_i\neq\lamba_j$ would force them to be multiples as I can't think of a counter example. However I appreciate your opinion.

Comment: You’re not looking for simple-enough examples: consider $(1,2)$ and $(3,4)$.

Comment: There are both permutations of the type (1,1,2) in $S_4$ as $(1,2)=(1,2)(3)(4)$, $(3,4)=(1)(2)(3,4)$ and hence do not give a valid example because $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$.

Comment: @Hectorx: what about $(1,2)(3,4,5) = (3,4,5)(1,2)$?

Answer (score 2):

This is true. Because if $O$ is an orbit of $\alpha$, then so is $\beta(O)$. By the condition on cycle lengths, $\beta(O)=O$. So $O$ is left invariant by $\beta$.

On $O$, $\alpha$ acts as an $n$-cycle, where $|O|=n$. The only permutations commuting with this cycle are its powers. So that is how $\beta$ must act.

Since $O$ was an arbitrary orbit, this proves your claim.